# JavaScript: Difference between using Object.create and Object.assign for prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

In many tutorials on inheritance in JavaScript, including [Mozilla's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), they assign `Sub.prototype = Object.create(Sup.prototype)`, stating that `Object.create` will create a new object whose prototype is `Sup.prototype` and assign it to `Sub.prototype`.

What I don't get is, **why are they assigning an object whose prototype is `Sup.prototype` using `Object.create`, when they can assign a clone of the `Sup.prototype` object itself, directly, like `Sub.prototype = Object.assign({}, Sup.prototype)`**?

Comment: Well, it does not set up a inheritance chain. `instanceof` won't work, and it won't reflect any changes to `Sup.prototype` in `Sub.prototype` as properties are not dynamically inherited from it.

Answer (score 0):

With `Object.assign({}, Sup.prototype)`, it only copies over the owned properties, and only if they're enumerable. You're losing any inheritance that the `Sup.prototype` may be benefiting from.

```js
function Top() {}

// This method is enumerable, but inherited by Sup
Top.prototype.top = function() {
  console.log("top")
};

function Sup() {}
Sup.prototype = Object.create(Top.prototype, {
  sup: { // This method is non-enumerable
    value: function() {
      console.log("sup")
    }
  }
});

// So far so good...
var sup = new Sup();
sup.top()
sup.sup();

function Sub() {}
Sub.prototype = Object.assign({}, Sup.prototype);

// Not so good anymore...
var sub = new Sub();

try {
  sub.top();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e+"");
}
try {
  sub.sup();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e+"");
}
```